Horror short story : a character escapes from a sinister castle and finds a beautiful one
I read this horror short story, probably in a collection, about 20 years ago. But somehow I think it is much older than that.
The POV character lives alone in a sinister castle. He does not remember ever seeing any living human. Lots of human skeletons, but only rats and such unpleasant creatures seem to live there. I don't remember what he eats, but IIRC, mostly disgusting things. But some supplies seem to be there in abundance: he has candles to read books in the library. The books have images showing people, well dressed, eating nice food, dancing...
The castle is surrounded by a dark forest even more sinister. He has tried many times to escape but had given up each time, not finding an end to the forest and therefore going back.
But this time he does find the end, and after walking some time he sees a very nice castle. IIRC it is nighttime and he can see, already from a distance through french windows, a large room all lit up, with people looking and acting like in his books. He is happy to have finally found other living people and he enters the room through an open french window.
Immediately all the people in the room start to howl in horror and run away from all the openings but the one he is in. And when the room is empty he understands why they all fled : he sees across the room, beyond a door, another similar room where a horrible monster looks in his direction. He would like to run away but somehow he is attracted by that door and the monster is also approaching it. But when his hand reaches the door at the same time as the monster's hand what he touches is the smooth cold surface of a mirror.

This is The Outsider by H.P. Lovecraft. It ends precisely as you've described.

In his shock and surprise, he loses his balance and touches the creature. Horrified, he runs from the building back to his castle, where he tries unsuccessfully to crawl back through the grate into his old world. Cast out of his old existence, the narrator now rides with the "mocking and friendly ghouls on the night wind". Since he touched the monster's feet in the corner, he has felt nothing but the "cold and unyielding surface of the polished glass" of a mirror.


Also the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267921/amnesiac-character-wakes-up-in-a-strange-city-hunted-by-creatures/267923#267923

@Valorum Your quote is a bit terse, but the wiki page you pointed to is unmistakably the right one.

@FuzzyBoots the answer there is clearly about my story, but does not seem  fit the question there. No surprise it was not accepted.
